# Rails Models for multiple revisions of a type of document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to model this scenario with Rails

- There are three types of ApplicationForms- FormA, FormB and FormC

This scenario is modeled using Single Table inheritance. And each form has a method **tranform_to_pdf** overwritten, which returns a map(header-->value).

```
application_forms(id, name, type)
```

Now it is possible to have multiple revisions for each form, for example, FormA has Rev1, Rev2, etc. Each revision might have modifications to the number of fields present etc.

What would be the best way to modify existing rails model to reflect revisions?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `What would be the best way to modify existing rails model to reflect revisions?` Stack Overflow doesn't really work like this :) "what is the best way" questions lead to answers that are based on peoples differing opinions. Stack Overflow works best with questions that have one "right" answer. How about you have a go at solving this yourself. It doesn't matter if it doesn't work the best... you can improve the answer as you learn (refactor). If you get stuck on an error, come back and we will help you solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would delegate the work to a second set of objects. Assuming you have a `forms` table with 3 fields (`id`,  the polymorphic `type` and the `revision` (version) ). I would write something like:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class FormA < Form
  def transform_to_pdf
  end 

  private

  REVISION_TO_IMPLEMENTATION_MAP = {
    1 => FormAImplementationV1,
    2 => FormAImplementationV2
  }  

  def implementation
    klass = REVISION_TO_IMPLEMENTATION_MAP[revision]
    klass.new(self)
  end

end

class FormAImplementation 
  def initialize(model)
  end
end
class FormAImplementationV1 < FormAImplementation
  def transform_to_pdf
  end   
end
class FormAImplementationV2 < FormAImplementation
  def transform_to_pdf
  end   
end
```

However I think this could quickly become unwieldy and it would quickly make sense to implement another solution, either with meta-data or by storing revision and field in your database. I would need to see more code though...